# Dynamic price range filter in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a product model with attributes name, price, description, category.
I want to create a dynamic price range filter with check boxes in the view.
for example if I query my product like below:

get_products = Product.objects.filter(category='Men')

Now if the above query has a list of products with min_price = 500 and max_price=5000 then I would like to have 4 set of price range filters like below:
1)500-1500
2)1501-2500
3)2501-3800
4) 3801-5000

But the above should be dynamic based on min and max price value.

I have tried to use range(min,max,steps) but it is very difficult to generate a dynamic price range filter. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you show the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Djangos [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/) and go with s.th. like that:

```
# Imports
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models import Min

def price_range_filters(self):

    # Get Max and Min Value of Queryset
    max_price = Product.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price'))
    min_price = Product.objects.all().aggregate(Min('price'))

    # Split the range into 4
    range_step = (max_price - min_price) / 4

    # create context 
    context = {
        'max_price': max_price,
        'min_price': min_price,
        'range_step': range_step
    }

    # return objects and render page
    return render(request, 'your_site.html', context)
```

Then you can use the variables `max_price` + `min_price` + `range_step` on the client side to update your price range checkboxes using Javascript.

Depending on the logic of your html/frontend you could also wrap the ranges directly into your view in variables and render out those straightforward.

Comment: Great....! Thanks alot sir. For quite a couple of hours I was struggling to get this done but you helped me with a simple answer and within no time I achieved to what I was looking for. Thank you once again sir..!